# Unable to connect to a port from a remote machine in Centos?

Tags: networking, iptables, port

I am not able to connect to `9423` port of a machine from another machine though the local `telnet localhost 9423` works. Here is my `netstat -putna`. Is there anything suspicious? `10000` works just fine though.

```
[root@localhost etc]# netstat -putna
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5480                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3285/vami-lighttpd  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3475/perl           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3390/sshd           
tcp        0    300 192.168.5.80:22             172.29.14.11:42646          ESTABLISHED 5835/sshd           
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:9423       :::*                        LISTEN      6475/java           
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      3435/java           
tcp        0      0 :::5488                     :::*                        LISTEN      3183/vami-sfcbd     
tcp        0      0 :::5489                     :::*                        LISTEN      3183/vami-sfcbd     
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      3390/sshd           
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.5.80:80      ::ffff:172.29.14.11:43242   FIN_WAIT2   3435/java           
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.5.80:80      ::ffff:172.29.14.11:40142   ESTABLISHED 3435/java           
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.5.80:80      ::ffff:172.29.14.11:40402   ESTABLISHED 3435/java           
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.5.80:80      ::ffff:172.29.14.11:39538   ESTABLISHED 3435/java           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000               0.0.0.0:*                               3475/perl
```

Comment: Add a "-n" and you will see the address waiting for the incoming connections : 127.0.0.1. You allow the connections to 9423 only from loopback (your own machine) and not from the network (see here with the *). It is not the iptables result, iptables is the firewall

Comment: Why downvote? I don't know so I ask. There are so many levels of abstractions which all of us don't know. iptables can be one of the reasons why you are not able to access a port from outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned before, it has nothing to do with iptables. Your service is listening to local (loopback) interface only and therefore is unavailable from outside. You need to reconfigure your service. If you are not familiar with that, you may try the following.

1. Find configuration file of your service and make backup copy of it
2. Open the configuration file and search for string looks like `127.0.0.1:9423`
3. Replace it with the `0.0.0.0:9423` or `*:9423`
4. Restart your service and try again.